# Deferreadiness until User is loaded, but depends on Session (Ember.Simpleauth)

Tags: ember.js

I have found several Posts about how to defer the readiness in my application. In my case I wan't to defer it only if the user is authenticated and then load the user. But in the case that the user is not authenticated the App can be immediately started.

My current approach looks like this.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {

    Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen({
        user: function() {
          if (this.get('isAuthenticated')) {
            //hier müsste vielleicht der user mit der id 'me', dann gefunden werden
           return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 'me');
          }
        }.property('isAuthenticated')
      });

    container.register('app:authenticators:backend',  GambifyApp.BackendAuthenticator);
    container.register('app:ownauth:facebook',  GambifyApp.FacebookBackendAuthenticator);
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
    // By default the session is only injected into:['model', 'controller', 'view', 'route']
    container.injection('adapter', 'session', 'ember-simple-auth:session:current');
  }
});
```

And this is where I try to reload my user.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'preloadcurrentUser',
  after: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var session = container.lookup('ember-simple-auth:session:current');
    if(session.get('isAuthenticated')){
        GambifyApp.deferReadiness();
        container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 'me').then(function(){
          GambifyApp.advanceReadiness();
        });
    }

  }
});
```

The Problem is that when I check for isAuthenticated the session is only "initialized" but not yet loaded.

```
init: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.bindToStoreEvents();
    var restoredContent      = this.store.restore();
    var authenticatorFactory = restoredContent.authenticatorFactory;
    if (!!authenticatorFactory) {
      delete restoredContent.authenticatorFactory;
      this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory).restore(restoredContent).then(function(content) {
        _this.setup(authenticatorFactory, content);
      }, function() {
        _this.store.clear();
      });
    } else {
      this.store.clear();
    }
  },
```

The isAuthenticated is only changed after _this.setup. And that is only called after I want to initialize my User.

So the current flow is like this:

1. Authentication Init
   1.1 Session init
2. preLoadUser (but here not yet authenticated)
   --> session setup (which would then authenticate)

How could I hook into the setup of the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember.SimpleAuth.Session sets isAuthenticated before it's completely set up (see here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/lib/ember-simple-auth/session.js#L158). To find out when the session is authenticated you should probably use the sessionAuthenticationSucceeded action: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/api.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-sessionAuthenticationSucceeded

Comment: Also the question is why you need to defer readiness of your application until the user was loaded from the server?

Comment: Because after login I transition to a route, where the remote server adress depends on the logged in user. If I would not defer Readiness, I could not determine the route endpoint. That is why I would like to defer it. And to be honest, I don't really understand the apprach with sessionAuthenticationSucceeded. Should I deferReadiness in the restore and then in the sessionAUthenticationSucceeded action call the user and when the promis resolves advance?

Comment: The sessionAuthenticationSucceeded action is for the case when a user logs in successfully - but that's of course after the application is ready.

What you could do is probably listen for the session's "ember-simple-auth:session-authentication-succeeded" event and once that is fired load the user model and once the promise returned by that resolves, advance the app's readiness.